# Microsoft wireless adapter not working

Tags: microsoft, wireless-keyboards

I have the Microsoft wireless mouse and keyboard 2000, but the adapter isn't recognized. mouse and keyboard both light up, and the batteries are fresh.

Answer (score 0):

After you plug the device in you may need to press the sync button on one or both the device and receiver. I have used multiple Microsoft based wireless devices, keyboard and mouse and they have always worked fine. In fact, you should be able to use a single receiver plugged into a USB port for both devices as they should be intercompatible.